# Return promise asynchronously for a typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my HTML file I'm trying to customise an example from UI Bootstrap typeahead http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead.

This is my html:

```
  <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="MainController">

    <h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">
    <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>

  </div>
```

this is my js:

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.selected = undefined;

  $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    var prom = $http.get('http://myUrl', {
      params: {
        queryParam: val,
      }
    });
    return prom
  };

});
```

`myUrl` returns some objects as a JSON array, as the following:

```
[
    {
        place: "foo",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        place: "bar",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        place: "fooBar",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        place: "BarFoo",
        value: "#0ff"
    }
]
```

But data are not displayed in HTML page. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this:

```
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    return $http.get('http://myUrl', {
        params: {
            queryParam: val,
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        return response;
    }
};
```

Also I would suggest using $resource over $http.

Comment: I printed `console.log(response);` aftere `sucess` and I see that the code retrive an array of objects `[Object, Object, Object]` but are not displayed in HTML with typeahead fashion